# Find the cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A = <2i>$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. There are four cosets in $\Bbb{Z}[i]/A$. Determine the four cosets.

So we know the factor rings has elements $a + bi +<2i>$.

So $2i + <2i>$ = $0 + <2i>$, so we know $2i=0$, thus $i=0$, also $(2i)^2 = 0^2$.
Thus $-4$ = 0, we  can conclude $4 = 0$.

So then we know the costs are $0 + <2i>, 1 + <2i>, 2 + <2i>, 3 + <2i>$.

I wanted to confirm if this was the right answer and if my logic was correct.

Comment: Put math expressions inside dollar signs will make them neater.

Comment: Thus $i=0$? You don't know that $2$ is invertible mod $2i$. In fact, it isn't, as $2\in\langle 2i\rangle$. This also means that $2+\langle 2i\rangle=0+\langle 2i\rangle$, so your list has cosets written down twice. Moreover your list is also incomplete, as it fails to include $i+\langle 2i\rangle$ (for example).

Comment: okay so how should I figure out the correct cosets

Comment: @B ry note that $2\in \langle 2i\rangle$, so you can reduce $a$ and $b$ modulo 2 to get equivalent gaussian integers.

Comment: so the proper cosets are, $0 + <2i>, 1 + <2i>, i + <2i>, 1 + i + <2i>$

Answer (score 1):

in this simple case the algebra may be illuminated by a little geometric thinking

if you look at $2i\mathbb{Z}[i]$ you obtain the lattice of Gaussian integers rotated by $\arg(2i) = \frac{\pi}2$ and stretched by $|2i|=2$.

the rotation leaves the lattice invariant, so 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{2i\mathbb{Z}[i]} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{2\mathbb{Z}[i]}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my comment was going to be an answer so I'm reposting it here.
Note that $2\in \langle 2i\rangle$, so you can reduce $a$ and $b$ modulo 2 to get equivalent gaussian integers. Then note that there are therefore at most 4 equivalence classes $0+\langle 2i\rangle$, $1+\langle 2i\rangle$, $i+\langle 2i\rangle$, and $1+i+\langle 2i\rangle$. Since you claim there are four, these are all the cosets.

Comment: so how come $i \ne 0$

Comment: @B ry suppose $i \in \langle 2i\rangle$, then $i=2ik$ for some $k\in \Bbb{Z}[i]$ and this equality is true in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ cancellation holds, so that would imply $2k=1$ for some $k=a+bi$, but then $2a=1$ as an equality in $\Bbb{Z}$, which is impossible.

Comment: okay so can you explain how you knew $2 \in <2i>$

Comment: @B ry Sure, $2=2i\cdot (-i)$, so 2 is in $\langle 2i\rangle$

Comment: I think I need to brush up on cyclic groups! THanks for your input

Comment: @B ry, this is false if you regard these objects as groups. You have infinitely many cosets when you regard $\langle 2i\rangle$ as a cyclic group rather than an ideal.

Comment: Okay, I go ya now!

Comment: I know this is not proper forum educate but I have another small question to ask regarding this factor ring. 

Is $\langle 2i \rangle$ a prime ideal, maximal ideal, or neither?

Comment: @B ry Well $2=(1+i) (1-i)$, and $1+i, 1-i\not\in\langle 2i\rangle$ so the ideal is not prime and hence not maximal either.

Comment: OKay I appreciate all of your help, you are awesome!